# different string lengths from EncodeBase64 and TIDEncoderMime.EncodeStream

Tags: delphi

In the following code snippet, method1 causes showmessage to display 10048, while methods 2 and 3 display 9792. Which method is providing the correct encoding for use in an XML node? The filesize on disk is 7343. Thanks

```
DrawingField: AnsiString;
PicStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
encoder := TidEncoderMIME.Create(nil);
StringStream := TStringStream.Create('');
try
  Image1.Picture.LoadFromFile('Ryan.jpg');
  Image1.Picture.Graphic.SaveToStream(PicStream);

  {$ifdef METHOD1}
  DrawingField := EncodeBase64(PicStream.Memory, PicStream.Size);
  {$endif}
  {$ifdef METHOD2}
  PicStream.Position := 0;
  encoder.EncodeStream(PicStream, StringStream);
  DrawingField := StringStream.DataString;
  {$endif}
  {$ifdef METHOD3}
  PicStream.Position := 0;
  DrawingField := encoder.EncodeStream(PicStream, PicStream.Size);
  // SetString(DrawingField, PAnsiChar(PicStream.Memory), PicStream.Size);
  {$endif}

  ShowMessage(IntToStr(Length(DrawingField))); // 1 = 10048 2/3 = 9792
finally
  encoder.Free;
  PicStream.Free;
  StringStream.Free;
end;
```

Comment: Is one of them inserting line breaks? They are ignored in base64

Comment: Yes indeed, EncodeBase64 inserts line breaks every 75 characters. What does "They are ignored in Base64" mean? If I use EncodeBase64, must I remove the CR/LF's before assigning `CurrNode.Text := DrawingField;` OR does it not matter to XML?

Comment: depends on which variant of base64 you need. There are [many](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#Implementations_and_history)